# Is there anyway to deploy private Ethereum network that have automining feature along with no gas cost system?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ganache

I am creating `POC` web app using `Ganache` as a Blockchain network locally.
For now, I need to deploy everything to a testing server but the problem is that I still could not find the way to set up a private `Blockchain` network that has `automining` like what we have with `Ganache` locally also about the gas fee as well, when I develop locally I need to manually and ether to every newly created account for them to be able to make a transaction. But once when I deploy everything to the testing server, it would be better if I don't need to keep transferring ether since this is just a `POC` app on a private network anyway.

Any tools that I should take a look for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are roughly describing a demo chain or a PoA chain.

OpenEthereum has a [demo](https://openethereum.github.io/Private-development-chain) chain flag which uses [this spec](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum/blob/main/crates/ethcore/res/chainspec/instant_seal.json).

Alternatively, Almost all ETH1 clients support building PoA chains so you can cherry pick the EIP's you want to cinclude. Geth supports [clique](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network). OpenEthereum supports [AuRa](https://openethereum.github.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial) and clique.

If you want a production grade private network, i'd recommend either using AuRa or [QBFT](https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/latest/configure-and-manage/configure/consensus-protocols/qbft/) from GoQuorum.

Each client and its consensus algo have its own set of requirements like minimum number of validator nodes e.t.c.